# Bypass cases within a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I'm attempting to prevent additional cases within my switch statements from printing automatically when located below an initially satisfied case. Here is the code I'm building. I read previously that fallthrough is inevitable in switch statements(?) but I'm assuming there must be a way around this.

```
System.out.println("\nQ1) What is the capital of Alaska?");
        System.out.println("\n\t 1) Melbourne");
        System.out.println("\n\t 2) Anchorage");
        System.out.println("\n\t 3) Juneau\n");
        selection = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (selection){

        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
        break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("\nThat's correct!");

        case 1:
        case 2:
            System.out.println("\nSorry, that's incorrect.");


            if (selection == 3)
            { score++; }

        System.out.print("\nQ2) Can you store the value 'cat' in a variable of type int? ");
        answer = keyboard.next();

        switch (answer){

        case "No":
        case "no":
            System.out.println("\nThat's correct!");

        case "Yes":
        case "yes":
            System.out.println("\nSorry, 'cat' is a string. Int type variables can only store numbers."); 


        if (answer == "No" || answer == "no" )
        { score++; }

            System.out.print("\nQ3) What is the result of 9+6/3?");
            System.out.println("\n\t 1) 5");
            System.out.println("\n\t 2) 11");
            System.out.println("\n\t 3) 15/3\n");
            selection = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (selection){

        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
        break;      

        case 2:
        System.out.println("\nThat's correct!\n");

        case 1:
        case 3:
            System.out.println("\nSorry, that's incorrect.\n");

        if (selection == 2)
        { score++; }

        keyboard.close();

        System.out.print("Overall, you got " + score + " out of 3 correct.\n"
                + "Thanks for playng!");
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please provide the minimum code to reproduce the problem, not all your code.

Comment: @Steephen I'm looking for a way to avoid printing every case result that doesn't involve using break, since that stops all of the remaining code from running, and prevents the user from proceeding through the rest of the quiz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct term for this behavior is *fallthrough*. 
You need to end every case with a `break` statement to get the desired behaviour. You can think of the `case` keyword as some form of `goto`.

The typical structure of a *switch-case* statement in C and similar languages is

```
switch (var)  {
    case a:
       ... 
       break;
    case b:
       ....
       break;
    default:
       ...
}
```

Not only C but all the languages influenced from Fortran's computed GOTO feature fallthrough. The `break` statement is not required in languages like Pascal.

Source: Wikipedia

**EDIT:**

I have corrected your program:

```
System.out.println("\nQ1) What is the capital of Alaska?");
System.out.println("\n\t 1) Melbourne");
System.out.println("\n\t 2) Anchorage");
System.out.println("\n\t 3) Juneau\n");
selection = keyboard.nextInt();

switch (selection) {
    case 3:
        System.out.println("\nThat's correct!");
        score++;
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        System.out.println("\nSorry, that's incorrect.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
        break;
}

System.out.print("\nQ2) Can you store the value 'cat' in a variable of type int? ");
answer = keyboard.next();

switch (answer) {
    case "No":
    case "no":
        System.out.println("\nThat's correct!");
        score++;
        break;
    case "Yes":
    case "yes":
        System.out.println("\nSorry, 'cat' is a string. Int type variables can only store numbers."); 
        break;
}

System.out.print("\nQ3) What is the result of 9+6/3?");
System.out.println("\n\t 1) 5");
System.out.println("\n\t 2) 11");
System.out.println("\n\t 3) 15/3\n");
selection = keyboard.nextInt();

switch (selection) {
    case 2:
        System.out.println("\nThat's correct!\n");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
        break;      
}
```

It is now easy to see the error. You did not close the *switch-case* blocks which made the following statements a part of the block hence preventing their execution when used with break. You need separate *switch-case* blocks for checking each answer.

Comment: That makes sense, and I've tried the code with break, which obviously works. What I'm asking specifically, is if there is a way to continue running through the remainder of the statements that proceed the break. This particular program is meant to act as a quiz, so there would have to be a way to continue moving through the rest of the questions regardless of whether the user inputs the right or wrong answer.

Comment: @Rodanten Sorry, but I am not able to understand the problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Basically I'm stuck between two results. Using break after a case will prevent the remainder from running, but it also prevents the user from proceeding through the rest of the questions. Not using break allows the user to continue, but it also prints every case result, instead of just the one that corresponds to their selection. I'm looking for a way for the user to proceed AND skip over the cases that don't apply to the answer they choose.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

End each case statement block with a "break;"

Eg.

```
case 2:
    System.out.println("\nThat's correct!\n");
    break;
```

Comment: This was my previous solution, but since it stopped the remainder of the code from running, it doesn't allow for the user to proceed through the rest of the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

Switch case executions follow as explained below.. from the below example, if user inputs “1” then case 1 is executed, or input is “2” then case 2 is executed, it continues until number of cases included in the switch block.

1. However,  Switch-Case does not stop execution when it find the matching case until a break statement appears. To terminate flow from further execution of other cases, a break statement is mandatory in each case.
2. Default statement is executed if there is no matching case and the default statement is the last condition in the switch block. If the default statement appears as first block then it will be executed automatically even there is a matching case. So default statement should be the last block with-in the switch-case statement.

   ```
   switch (input) {
       case 1:  
          System.out.println (“User input is “+ input)
       break;

       case 2:  
          System.out.println (“User input is “+ input)
       break;

       case 3:  
          System.out.println (“User input is “+ input)
        break;

       - - - - 
       - - - -
       - - - -
       default:
          System.out.println(” Invalid input“);
   }
   ```

Comment: This leads me to believe what I'm trying to do might not be possible. If proceeding cases will always execute until a break is achieved, it would not be possible for the user to proceed beyond a break statement to the remaining questions, while also not seeing the print of the other cases that don't correspond with their selection.

Comment: @rodanten, I'm not sure in which languages you are trying to implement the solution, however you can do it with simple recursive function.

Comment: @Lakshay Garg was actually able to help me achieve the output I was searching for. The solution was quite simple in the end. Thanks for your assistance as well.